# RxJava thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, rx-java

Is this code thread-safe?

```
Observable<String> observable = ... // some observable that calls
                                    // onNext from a background thread

observable
  .scan(new ArrayList<String>(), (List<String> acc, String next) -> {
    acc.add(next);
    return acc;
  })
  .subscribe( list -> {
    // do somethind with sequence of lists
    ...
  });
```

I'm curious because ArrayList is not a thread-safe data structure.

Comment: The Rx design guidelines are helpful: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is SerializedSubject necessary for thread-safety in RxJava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841809/is-serializedsubject-necessary-for-thread-safety-in-rxjava)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a quick answer, in .NET (the original Rx implementation) all values from an observable sequence can be assumed to be sequential. This does not preclude it to be multi-threaded. However if you are producing values in a multi-threaded manner, then you may want enforce the sequential nature by looking for the equivalent function to the .NET  `Synchronize()` Rx operator.

Another option is to check the implementation of `Scan` in the RxJava source code, to validate that it does enforce the sequential nature you would want/expect to provide you safety in your accumulator function.

Comment: `scan` in RxJava does exactly the same as the .Net original version.

Comment: Cheers. I mainly say that as over time I cant be sure that the .NET and Java code bases will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

If this code isn't thread-safe, then either RxJava is broken or your Observable source is broken - operators being non-reentrant is part of the Rx contract.

Comment: And this could be enforced with Rx's `Checked()` observer operator, if RxJava actually implemented it.  Pull request, anyone?

Comment: Thread safety for blocks is not so simple in my opinion. In the code shown in the post doesn't contain much detail. I guess what @orionll didn't notice is that the subscription is delivered synchronously by default. But if it was converted into an async subscription, then accessing the array list would not be safe any more.

Comment: @allprog You are correct that this isn't so simple, but this is one of the advantages of Rx, in that it does the work behind the scenes to make this safe.

Comment: What I'm saying is that as soon as the programmer is able to insert an arbitrary function in a block that can operate on global state, thread safety is not any more a decidable problem without knowing the complete context. The source code of scan shows that it will be safe as long as the initial list supports concurrency or not accessed in a global context. But this statement refers only that single object. If the block contains management of the global app state, then thread safety can hardly be decided by looking only at the code of the block.