# Is SerializedSubject necessary for thread-safety in RxJava

Tags: java, thread-safety, rx-java

I created a `Subject` instance in RxJava and call its `onNext()` from multiple threads:

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
//...
subject.onNext("A");  //thread A
subject.onNext("B");  //thread B
```

The [RxJava documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject) says that:

> take care not to call its `onNext( )` method (or its other on methods) from multiple threads, as this could lead to non-serialized calls, which violates the Observable contract and creates an ambiguity in the resulting `Subject`.

- Do I have to call `toSerialized()` on such `Subject` assuming I don't care if `"A"` goes before or after `"B"`? How would serialization help?
- Is `Subject` thread-safe anyway or will I break RxJava without `toSerialized()`?
- What is the "*Observable contract*" that the documentation mentions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I have to call toSerialized() on such Subject assuming I don't care if "A" goes before or after "B"?

Yep use `toSerialized()` because all operators applied to the subject assume that proper serialization is occurring upstream. The stream may fail or produce unexpected results if this does not happen.

> Is Subject thread-safe anyway or will I break RxJava without toSerialized()?

answered above

> What is the "Observable contract" that the documentation mentions?

[Rx Design Guidelines.pdf](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) section 4 defines the Observable contract:

> **4.2. Assume observer instances are called in a serialized fashion**
>
> As Rx uses a push model and .NET supports multithreading, it is possible for different messages to arrive different execution contexts at the same time. If consumers of observable sequences would have to deal with this in every place, their code would need to perform a lot of housekeeping to avoid common concurrency problems. Code written in this fashion would be harder to maintain and potentially suffer from performance issues.

I think RxJava documentation should make this more discoverable so I'll raise an issue.

Comment: Is this a requirement for **BehaviorSubject** as well?

Answer (score 3):

According to Dave's answer, if you know **beforehand** that your Subject is going to be accessed from different threads, you could wrap it into a `SerializedSubject`
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/SerializedSubject.html

> Wraps a Subject so that it is safe to call its various on methods from different threads.

like: 
`private final Subject<Object, Object> bus = new SerializedSubject<Object, Object>(PublishSubject.create());`

(taken from Ben Christensen's EventBus example here: http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/04eef9ca0851f3a5d7bf )

Comment: When look at the source code:

`public final SerializedSubject<T, R> toSerialized() {
        if (getClass() == SerializedSubject.class) {
            return (SerializedSubject<T, R>)this;
        }
        return new SerializedSubject<T, R>(this);
    }`

New a SerializedSubject instead of using toSerialized() will prevent to create unnecessary new instances in memory, so this answer is still better.